# How Sessions are maintained by Server

Tags: apache, session, web-applications, webserver

Anyone know how a web server (apache, tomcat) maintains sessions ?

I know how to create / handle and destroy sessions. What I need to know is how server maintains sessions internally.

i.e if 10 users are connected to the server, how the server identifies which session belongs to a particular user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, your webserver (Apache) doesn't have a concept for "session"; it merely understands [requests according to the HTTP protocol](http://www.garshol.priv.no/download/text/http-tut.html).

In fact, HTTP is famous for being a "stateless protocol" - there is no concept of "session". This is fundamental to the scalability of HTTP, but makes it hard to build web applications that need state.

So different web application frameworks have introduced the concept of "session".

Tomcat is not strictly speaking a web server, it's a servlet container.

Comment: hmm, so for example if I am using apache and running a php application (may be a social network website) ... what is the session thing ?

Comment: PHP has its own session mechanism; it's similar in concept to the Java implementation, but delivered by the PHP framework, not Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Sessions are usually identified by a cookie with a unique ID for each user. The ID is generated and sent as a cookie when the session is first created (i.e. when the user doesn't already have a cookie).

Another way that's sometimes seen is keeping the session ID in the URL, which is used when the client refuses to accept cookies for some reason. This has numerous drawbacks though, such as security issues if the user pastes their URL to another user, having to add the ID to all links, and ugly URLs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Matti ..
Now if a person sniffs in between server and user, and gets the cookie, he can use the same session too, wouldn't that be a security problem ?

Comment: @user1656168: You are correct, and this is why you should use HTTPS on any site that you consider sensitive enough for people to go through the trouble of making a man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: One more question though, If I copy my cookie to some other machine, I can use the same session , right ??

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: If all that identifies the session is a cookie, yes, you can.

Comment: Another question poped in my mind ... when a user restarts its browser, he cannot use the same session (i. he has to login again).. so by your logic of cookie, how this thing is handled by the "Server"

Comment: @userrandomnumbers: This is taken care of by the browser. If you set a cookie without an expiration date, the browser will delete it when it thinks that "the current session" has ended - this used to be when the browser window was closed, but today it's more complicated with session saving and whatever. In the end, you can't really know for sure that the user has closed their browser.

Comment: Here's a good write-up of session hijacking...http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking